# How fast are Ingenuity's knees wearing out?

Tags: landing, ingenuity, sensors, legs, lifetime

Each leg of Ingenuity has what I'll call a knee.  After just a few flights, on 2021 May 10, [NASA](https://mars.nasa.gov/technology/helicopter/status/301/keeping-our-feet-firmly-on-the-ground/) wrote:

> By plastically deforming and fatiguing as it absorbs energy, this flexure acts much like the crumple zone structure of a car chassis. However, unlike a car or the crumple-cushioned landing gear of the Apollo moon landers, Ingenuity’s titanium springs rebound after each impact to pull these aluminum dampers back into shape for the next landing. The aluminum damper gets a little bit weaker with each cycle as cracks and creases develop. While it would eventually break after a few hundred hard landings, with only a few flights scheduled for this demonstration, that’s a problem we could only dream of having.

Almost a year later, it's had 23 flights.  Have any of its sensors, such as its IMU or altimeter, yet been able to detect how quickly this expected gradual cracking is developing?  Has some threshold been chosen, beyond which Ingenuity should stick to only gentle landings?

BrendanLuke15's comment's linked paper says the damper is "1100-series annealed aluminum" whose damping is "largely independent of temperature or atmospheric pressure."  But how does one apply fatigue datasheets for 1100 to this particular shape (1 x 2 cm?  0.5 mm thick?  deflecting how much and how fast)?  How differently would a partially fatigued damper behave (as if it were half as thick because of cracks)?  Could that behavior be measured by Ingenuity?

Comment: Do we have any indication that there were any "hard landings" so far?

Comment: I'm thinking "a few hundred" is still a low-ball estimate. This sort of tech is nothing revolutionary, pretty common in mid-tier commercial drones, and the durability goes easily into tens of thousands of landings.

Comment: [Pipenberg, B. et al. "Design and Fabrication of the Mars Helicopter Rotor, Airframe, and Landing Gear Systems," AIAA 2019-0620. AIAA Scitech 2019 Forum. January 2019.](https://doi.org/10.2514/6.2019-0620) would help but it's paywalled. [Here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Design-and-Fabrication-of-the-Mars-Helicopter-and-Pipenberg-Keennon/f3a9de0f5ea5ab61cd9ea9d4ae616ed391fd2d45/figure/10) is a annotated figure close up view of the "knee" from that paper

Comment: @asdfex Good question. I would also ask "what are the definitions of hard vs gentle landings?"

Comment: @SF. can you give an example of one? I can't seem to find any with legs/"knees" quite like this

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 Probably because you're still thinking too high-tech, and seeking professional references and white papers. It's much closer to [cheapo toy drone legs](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003698805566.html?channel=twinner) where a simple spring (or in the linked case, a flexible plastic tab) allows a little bit of motion outwards upon hard landing, absorbing some energy.

Comment: @SF there is a very large difference between a simple spring loaded leg and a DAMPED TRAVEL leg. Imagine a pickup truck with a heavy load in its box. With just springs on the axle the truck would bounce and bounce and bounce until the energy was dissipated as heat in the springs. The damping element works against the system 'ringing' so the helicopter can minimize landing bounce.   I'd guess the carbon fiber legs are pretty stiff and not flexing (springing) much.

Comment: @BradV The difference might be large if Ingenuity was landing on solid rock surface, not on sand. I doubt the flexure flexes much at all there. While its motor and rotor assembly definitely face challenges of Mars atmosphere, the landing assembly really doesn't encounter anything commercial drones don't. In particular, at <2kg, it's more comparable to the the amateur/hobby/toy class than pro-sumer, and these tend to withstand quite a bit of abuse without expensive gear. Sure you can't set Ingenuity upright if it tips over, but then a bit softer landing can be programmed in too.

Comment: @SF the drone leg you link to is not really a knee and does not appear to provide dissipation of landing impact. At fully deployed position the leg is rigid, providing virtually no damping. If leg were positioned at vertical position (maximum platform height) the pointed foot contact with ground would be directly under the pivot so pivot wouldn't move on perfectly vertical landing and could collapse inwards during sideways impact.

Comment: "At fully deployed position the leg is rigid, providing virtually no damping " - only if you consider the materials rigid or perfectly springy. These legs are angled outwards, and the construction provides just enough flex they work. Of course this isn't carefully engineered to work so, it just happens as natural consequence of cheap materials and sloppy design. But these legs still can withstand a thousand rough landings just fine, and just think how much better one can do *with* careful engineering and quality materials.

Comment: @SF I agree with you that the damper gets exercised very little unless the copter battery empties faster than copter can land under standard autonomous control resulting in descent rate faster than desired. I would guess nominal programming is designed to provide VERY soft landing.   You raise a good point!  What kinds of surfaces IS Ingenuity landing on? Sand dune, thin dust over rock, bare rock, grassy meadow? ;-)

Comment: @BradV Nearly universally flat sandy surfaces. How deep the sand reaches is hard to determine, but there's at least a couple centimeters of it at all landing sites (some may have much more, again, we don't know). At one point the sand was so soft one of the legs sunk some 4 centimeters in, the "ball" leg completely buried, this required a very sharp start not to allow the helicopter to tip over, in normal cases the legs leave about 2cm deep indents.

Comment: Also, the battery always held a good reserve of power, the limiting factor of flight length being energy dissipation - the motor heating up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me open by saying I do not have an answer.

Thanks BrendanLuke15 for linking to the knee detail image!!

While question is more "design/engineering" than "space exploration"... still very fun to consider!

I used a 1000 series aluminum in a design about 30 years ago. I do not recall the specific alloy, but I
selected it because it was almost dead soft. This 1100 alloy damper is very similar in properties. It is
not heat treatable, nor would one want higher properties.

I suspect Camille Goudeseune recognises that Ingenuity will not be significantly compromised if the
dampers break, but my concern would be uneven bounce when some dampers break and others don't.

The dampers are not load bearing elements and the legs will still hold Ingenuity when dampers break.

my comments in red

[image]